# Explanation for a simple "saving the file" code

Tags: android, storage, android-fileprovider

I want to learn more about Android apps.
So, I want an explanation of the **out=context.openFileOutput** arguments .

```
public void saveImage(Context context, Bitmap b,String name,String extension){
name=name+"."+extension;
FileOutputStream out;
try {
    out = context.openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try with this. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html# --> openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a programming Q&A, not a learning place. Use [Google](https://www.google.com) to search for tutorials.

Comment: its really random in google search and the concepts they used are really hard to understand .

Comment: What concepts are there? You know what method you are trying to use, so read the API

Comment: bro. the android main page is totally hard to understand some concepts even if found the API in it .

Comment: `I want an explanation` ... You **want**. Really!

Comment: Its just a words hahah . I didnt mean it to be order if u know what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`out` is a `FileOutputStream` that is created in order to save the Bitmap to the file that is created or opened by `context.openFileOutput` with the name of the value of `name`

Comment: Thank you for the answer . Do you think this fun. Will be work and what should i pass to the context arg. ?

Comment: Pass it whatever you want as long as the object types match. I'm not writing your app, so you have to test yourself if it works.   (Any Activity class is a Context)

Comment: Thank you for all this explanation .